# Segmented circular progress bar in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-progressbar

How to create segmented circular progress bar in android like the one given below?

[segmented circular progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtHGJ.jpg)

I am not able to find a solution

Comment: I need this too. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Anyone find this solution yet?